# Collaborative editing in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, word-2013-preview

Is there a way to edit the same document with your friends at the same time using Microsoft Office Word 2013? How?

Comment: Do you save your documents to SkyDrive?

Comment: I can save my documents to skydrive, but I dont know what to do to allow my friend to edit my documents.

Answer (score 2):

If you save the document to OneDrive (for which support is now built in to Office 2013), you can [log in to OneDrive](http://onedrive.com/), navigate to the file in question, click the check box top left of the file's tile, then choose Share from the menu at the top of the screen. One of the options is to allow recipients to be able to edit the file.

Comment: Note: In 2014 SkyDrive has been renamed to OneDrive.